Habilitar CORS en Virtualbox con Ubuntu
Buen día a todos.
Estoy usando Virtualbox para ejecutar Ubuntu20.04, en el cual quiero acceder a un servidor con un servicio que instalé, sin embargo me sale el error de failed to fetch, estuve revisando y veo que es el cors.

No sé cómo habilitarlos en una VM, estuve probando y habilitando los adaptadores de red pero no me funciono.

Espero sus consejos y ayuda, muchas gracias de antemano.
